# Java OutOfMemoryError in a program that creates Strings

Tags: java

I was answering a [codingbat question](http://codingbat.com/prob/p172063), but when I run my code, I get this error:

```
Well done the answer is, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
at CodingBat.extraFront(CodingBat.java:24)
at CodingBat.main(CodingBat.java:7)
```

My Code is:

```
public class CodingBat {


public static void main(String[] args){
    CodingBat object = new CodingBat();
    System.out.print("Well done the answer is, ");
    System.out.print(object.extraFront("Test"));          

}




public String extraFront(String str) {
    int x = 1;
    String string;
    if(str.length() == 0)
        return "";
    else if(str.length() == 1)
        string = str.substring(0,1);
    else
        string = str.substring(0,2);
    while(x <= 2){
        string += string;
    }
    return string;
}


}
```

Comment: You have run out of memory.  The while loop being the source of problem. What if x is less that 3 ?.. 'string += string;' will execute forever

Comment: you should look at while(x<=2)

Comment: Well done the answer is, Exception in thread "main" .. lol.. that was in deed funny

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinite loop that keeps creating longer and longer Strings until you run out of memory:

```
while(x <= 2){
    string += string;
}
```

Since you have a condition that depends on `x`, you might want to increment `x` inside the while loop (or use a for loop instead) :

```
while(x <= 2){
    string += string;
    x++;
}
```

or

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 2; x++) { // remove the previously declared x variable
    string += string;
}
```

Comment: And for better performance, don't do `string += string`. Use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the loop that never exit.

```
while(x<=2){
    // whatever
    x++;
}
```

It stacks the string until memory break.